# Can't import BIP32 key into electrum

Tags: private-key

I always struggle here and tried both ways plenty of time

i use the rubygem "moneytree" and electrum 3.3

```
@master = MoneyTree::Master.new
@master.to_bip32(:private)
```

this will give me `tprv8ZgxMBicQKsPe8hnfLVQdtZk2qMKnnDQs2ZKLgoJQBhedKQ5vB7srAb6Tk2iUYNkhaacTjNP9WzkbjCqPjk8ExUFGECbiR1Z8tZDs76jytn`

however, i can't import this in electrum. the `next` button is just non active.

---

i tried the other way around and created a wallet with seed `fabric body bright coffee special music virus raccoon side double shield shrug` and exported the master public key which will gives me `xpub661MyMwAqRbcGq54zC5FfD3rTjgcAGd36JvtW6r4RGheQjSdUVqAS9Q1DLAvzyvvxdYziZced4Y6kHLCqo73vuB4gGSpt6tJwtCWYm8zsBb`

now i'll run the following

```
master_pub_key = "xpub661MyMwAqRbcGq54zC5FfD3rTjgcAGd36JvtW6r4RGheQjSdUVqAS9Q1DLAvzyvvxdYziZced4Y6kHLCqo73vuB4gGSpt6tJwtCWYm8zsBb"
$bitcoin_root_node = MoneyTree::Node.from_bip32(master_pub_key)

i = 0
20.times do
  p $bitcoin_root_node.node_for_path("m/0/#{i}").to_address
  i+= 1
end
```

all generated addresses will look like this

```
mpQPcBLyTqPPCw9dhdXYm3Dvnnn58Y4dwA
mt6UdprJNAuJUtG3BYWTy3dZrST7nZTwtZ
```

starting with a small M

however, in electrum all the addresses are starting with `1xxxxx`

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like in some places you're using testnet addresses (`tprv..`, `m..`) and in other places you're using mainnet addresses (`xpub..`, `1..`). If your software is expecting one and gets the other, then you'll likely have some problems (like Electrum not letting you click 'next'). Check to make sure all the software you're using is configured to give you the desired outputs.

See: https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes

Comment: thanks buddy. i used my own fork where i made testnet true unless specified otherwise. i forgot about. i'm so stupid :)